# MySQL JSON UPDATE ON DUPLICATE KEY column merge removing empty array wrapper

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am having weird issue with updating JSON column in MySQL. I am developing a plugin on WordPress platform. Here is the scenario.

In the `cart` table I have a column `customers` the default value is `NULL` for the column.

On duplicate I am updating row with the update values for few columns including the `customers` column.

### SQL Query

```
INSERT INTO {$this->pg_table} ({$imploded_column}) 
VALUES({$imploded_format}) ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE qty = qty + '%d', customers = JSON_MERGE(customers, '%s'), added_at = now()
```

### Customer data

```
$this->customers = json_encode($customers);
```

The above code will insert json as `{"Jatin Soni": "rdyad@email.com"}`. However, if the `$customers` is empty, it will insert `[]` empty array.

Now `ON DUPLICATE KEY 
    UPDATE` using `JSON_MERGE` it will wrap as `[{"Jatin Soni": "rdyad@email.com"}]` as the `$customers` was empty.

So I can not be sure if the `customer` column value is `{"Jatin Soni": "rdyad@email.com"}` or `[{"Jatin Soni": "rdyad@email.com"}]` which is depend on user when they set the field value.

Additionally, I have tried setting null value if `$customers` is empty.

```
$this->customers     = empty($customers) ? NULL : json_encode($customers);
```

> WordPress prepare method doesn't allow to insert NULL so the column
>   will set to empty instead.

So the column will be empty if no data. In that case it is giving error when someone Updates. As I believe this is because in `JSON_MERGE(customers, '%s')` the `customers` is empty while it needs a JSON.

> **Question:**
>
> How can I keep the json string structure consistent in all
>   above cases?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround but I am still looking for the proper solution rather than this one.

Here I have added empty json string if `$customers` is empty.

```
$this->customers = empty($customers) ? '{}' : json_encode($customers);
```